# Kali: Sound Card not Detected

Tags: kali-linux, audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I recently purchased a new laptop with windows and proceeded to install linux (first Arco then Kali) and encountered problems with the sound card not being detected (on both distros - both used Gnome as DE).

Here is the `alsa-info` command output

```
upload=true&script=true&cardinfo=
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.4.65
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Fri Mar 26 13:46:00 UTC 2021


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

ID_LIKE=debian


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      Razer
Product Name:      Book 13 - RZ09-0357
Product Version:   0.04
Firmware Version:  1.01
System SKU:        RZ09-03571GM1
Board Vendor:      Razer
Board Name:        MA310


!!ACPI Device Status Information
!!---------------

/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI0003:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI000C:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI000E:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ELAN0406:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33A1:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT340E:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT34C5:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3F0D:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INTC1040:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INTC1043:01/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INTC1043:02/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INTC1043:03/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INTC1043:04/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INTC1044:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INTC1051:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:00/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:05/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:06/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:07/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:08/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:09/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:0a/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:0b/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:0c/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:0d/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:0e/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/MSFT0101:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:02/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:04/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C09:01/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0A:03/status      31
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0C:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0D:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0E:00/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:00/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:01/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:02/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:03/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:04/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:05/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:06/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:07/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP00001:00/status     11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP00001:01/status     11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:06/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:4c/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:98/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:99/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:9a/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:9c/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:9d/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:9e/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:a3/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:aa/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:ab/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:ac/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:b0/status   15


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    5.10.0-kali4-amd64
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         unknown
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k5.10.0-kali4-amd64
Library version:    1.2.4
Utilities version:  1.2.4


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------



!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

--- no soundcards ---


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller [8086:a0c8] (rev 20)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound


!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_hda_intel: model=generic
snd_hda_intel: model=auto


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------


!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Mar 26 14:41 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Mar 26 14:41 /dev/snd/timer


!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...

ARECORD

arecord: device_list:274: no soundcards found...

!!Amixer output
!!-------------


!!Alsactl output
!!--------------

--startcollapse--
--endcollapse--


!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

ac
acpi_pad
acpi_tad
acpi_thermal_rel
aesni_intel
ansi_cprng
autofs4
battery
binfmt_misc
bluetooth
br_netfilter
bridge
btbcm
btintel
btrtl
btusb
button
ccm
cec
cfg80211
configfs
coretemp
crc16
crc32_pclmul
crc32c_generic
crc32c_intel
crc_t10dif
crct10dif_common
crct10dif_generic
crct10dif_pclmul
cryptd
crypto_simd
ctr
dcdbas
dell_wmi_descriptor
dm_crypt
dm_mod
drbg
drm
drm_kms_helper
ecc
ecdh_generic
efi_pstore
efivarfs
evdev
ext4
fan
fat
fuse
ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper
hid
hid_generic
hid_multitouch
hid_sensor_als
hid_sensor_hub
hid_sensor_iio_common
hid_sensor_trigger
i2c_algo_bit
i2c_hid
i2c_i801
i2c_smbus
i915
iTCO_vendor_support
iTCO_wdt
idma64
industrialio
industrialio_triggered_buffer
int3400_thermal
int3403_thermal
int340x_thermal_zone
intel_cstate
intel_hid
intel_ish_ipc
intel_ishtp
intel_ishtp_hid
intel_lpss
intel_lpss_pci
intel_pmc_bxt
intel_pmc_core
intel_powerclamp
intel_rapl_common
intel_rapl_msr
intel_soc_dts_iosf
intel_uncore
ip_tables
irqbypass
iwlmvm
iwlwifi
jbd2
jitterentropy_rng
joydev
kfifo_buf
kvm
kvm_intel
ledtrig_audio
libaes
libarc4
libcrc32c
llc
mac80211
mbcache
mc
mei
mei_me
mmc_core
msr
nf_conntrack
nf_conntrack_netlink
nf_defrag_ipv4
nf_defrag_ipv6
nf_nat
nf_tables
nfnetlink
nft_chain_nat
nft_compat
nft_counter
nls_ascii
nls_cp437
nvme
nvme_core
overlay
pcspkr
processor_thermal_device
razerkbd
rfkill
rng_core
rtsx_pci
rtsx_pci_sdmmc
snd
snd_compress
snd_hda_codec
snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core
snd_hda_ext_core
snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep
snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_pcm
snd_soc_acpi
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match
snd_soc_core
snd_soc_dmic
snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_sof
snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_ipc
snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp
snd_timer
soundcore
soundwire_bus
soundwire_cadence
soundwire_generic_allocation
soundwire_intel
sparse_keymap
stp
sunrpc
t10_pi
thunderbolt
tpm
tpm_crb
tpm_tis
tpm_tis_core
usb_common
usbcore
usbhid
uvcvideo
veth
vfat
video
videobuf2_common
videobuf2_memops
videobuf2_v4l2
videobuf2_vmalloc
videodev
watchdog
wmi
wmi_bmof
x86_pkg_temp_thermal
x_tables
xfrm_algo
xfrm_user
xhci_hcd
xhci_pci
xt_MASQUERADE
xt_addrtype
xt_conntrack
xt_nat
xt_tcpudp


!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------



!!Packages installed
!!--------------------

ii  alsa-utils                               1.2.4-1                         amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
```

I tried several solutions, such as [this one](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html) and [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/739431/what-to-do-if-sound-goes-to-dummy-output) amongst others, unfortunatel without success.

I also verfied that `$USER` is indeed in the group `audio`.

Any help would be apprecitated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same similar issue. I believe the wrong kernel driver might be used by default (in my case it was `sof-audio-pci` which can be checked by having a look at `lspci -v`).

What worked for me was changing the defaulsts drivers used to `snd_hda_intel` which can be done as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243369/sound-card-not-detected-ubuntu-20-04-sof-audio-pci):

1. Enter the default grub file with `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
2. Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="..."` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="... snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"`
3. Apply the changes with `sudo update-grub`
4. Reboot

If you are not using grub, just check how to change the default audio drivers on your system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

```
sudo apt install pipewire-pulse
```