# No Sound Problem In Kali 2023.1

Tags: kali-linux, audio, pulseaudio

I've installed Kali 2023.1. Although I tried all sound driver, sound not working. But when I plugged any device like headphone It's working. I also tried Kali other version and Ubuntu latest version but It didn't work.

My laptop has dual boot Windows 11 and Kali.

GPU: RTX 4080 Mobile
CPU: i9 13900hx

I have tried these steps:

https://www.kali.org/docs/troubleshooting/no-sound/

https://stevemats.medium.com/fix-sound-issue-in-kali-linux-2021-4-babbed3cce0

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/406/how-to-enable-the-sound-on-kali-linux

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/643308

https://askubuntu.com/a/1400275

https://askubuntu.com/a/1277167

```
lspci | grep -i audio

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 7a50 (rev 11)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 22bc (rev a1)
```

Comment: Kali is ill advised. Try Fedora 37 instead.

Comment: If you're new to Linux, [Kali isn't for you](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/). It's not a desktop distro like Ubuntu, it's a security professional's toolbox. A lot of things are intentionally "broken" as they're either irrelevant or pose a security risk for the purpose. To avoid unnecessary headaches and making things more difficult than they have to be, I'd suggest installing a proper desktop distro for your dual boot, and if you're interested in learning pentesting use Kali as a [Virtual Machine](https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-virtual-machines).

Comment: no I am not newbie in kali. I used it in my old laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I went here and completed these steps. This worked for me.

https://www.kali.org/docs/troubleshooting/no-sound/

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work